How to clip multipart polygons in ArcGIS Pro using editing tools
I have numerous multipart polygons running along corridors that I am trying to "split" at intersections.  The polygons may or may not be present at the intersections, but there are always polygon parts in between intersections.
As an example below, lets say I want to clip/split/cut (not to be confused with editing/geoprocessing tools) the multipart polygon (GREEN) with a generic boundary (ORANGE).  I would like to "cut" out the green multipart polygon inside the orange polygon, creating a new multipart green polygon, while removing the "cut" portion from the original green multipart polygon. Ideally, I would like to draw the cutting polygon interactively with my mouse instead of creating the orange polygon feature.

EDIT:To be clear, I would like to keep the the green parts within the orange cutter as a new feature, while removing the green parts from the original feature.
I've tried the following, possibly incorrectly:

Split editing tool - does not work on multipart polygons
Clip editing tool - does not work on multipart polygons
Copy/Paste then edit vertices - time consuming
Explode editing tool (with parts option) then merge - can be very time consuming; only works well when a part doesn't need split.

Are there tools/techniques available in ArcGIS Pro that can do what I am wanting?

It seems that Erase tool is your only option. So, create another layer first

You might try the explode tool with the parts option.  https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/help/editing/explode-a-multipart-feature.htm

@FelixIP I hadn't thought of the Erase tool.  However, I want to keep the parts within the orange cutter as a new feature (question edited for clarification)

What you are describing is a chain of 3 tools: Erase, Clip, Merge (outputs from erase and clip). If you want to do it one by one, script below is real easy to modify, just include target.intersect(eraser) and use insertCursor.

I'd attach script below to menu button and use it while editing ERASER layer only.
Script will run instantly without asking for parameters, because there are none or, more accurately they are hardcoded.
To make it work you need to have layers named accordingly:

and adjust script to PRO syntax.
Script:
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
[TARGET,ERASER] = [arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd,item)[0] for item in "TARGET","ERASER"]
G = arcpy.Geometry()
for item in TARGET,ERASER:
    sel = item.getSelectionSet()
    if sel==None or len(sel)>1:
        arcpy.AddWarning("\nSelect 1 feature in each layer\n")
        exit()
eraser = arcpy.management.CopyFeatures(ERASER, G)[0]
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(TARGET,"Shape@") as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        target = row[0]
        target = target.difference(eraser)
        row[0] = target
        cursor.updateRow(row)
arcpy.RefreshActiveView()

In the pictures below, TARGET layer labelled by OID. So, before:

and after:


Since I was unable to find an OOTB solution, and python tools were not ideal for my situation, I wanted to post my solution.  I created an addin with the ArcGIS Pro SDK, and implemented a Map Tool to achieve the functionality I was after.
The tool expects a selection and allows the user to draw a clipping geometry, works on single- or multi-part geometries, and results in a new geometry representing the geometric intersection of our original geometry and clipping geometry, while the original geometry is updated with the geometric difference. Edits are added to the stack so that undo/redo is possible.
Code:
public CookieCutterTool() {
    IsSketchTool = true;
    SketchType = SketchGeometryType.Polygon;
    SketchOutputMode = SketchOutputMode.Map;
    UseSnapping = true;
    UseSelection = true;
}

protected override Task<bool> OnSketchCompleteAsync(Geometry sketchGeom) {
// check for selection
if (MapView.Active.Map.SelectionCount == 1) {
    return QueuedTask.Run(() => {
        // do something
        var selectionDict = MapView.Active.Map.GetSelection().ToDictionary();
        foreach (var kvp in selectionDict) {
            MapMember mapMember = kvp.Key;  // layer
            long oid = kvp.Value[0];        // ObjectID

            var insp = new Inspector();
            insp.Load(mapMember, oid);
            var oGeom = insp["SHAPE"] as Geometry;

            // make sure our selection overlaps our sketch
            if (!GeometryEngine.Instance.Disjoint(oGeom, sketchGeom)) {

                // create new edit operation
                var op = new EditOperation() { Name = "Cookie Cutter" };

                // grab dictionary of fields and values
                var nDict = insp.ToDictionary(a => a.FieldName, a => a.CurrentValue);

                // remove non editable and geometry fields
                IEnumerable<ArcGIS.Desktop.Editing.Attributes.Attribute> attributes = insp;
                foreach (var att in attributes) {
                    if (!att.IsEditable || att.FieldType == FieldType.Geometry) {
                        nDict.Remove(att.FieldName);
                    }
                }
                // add back in geometry field with value of intersection geometry
                nDict["SHAPE"] = GeometryEngine.Instance.Intersection(oGeom, sketchGeom);

                op.Create(insp.MapMember, nDict);
                if (!op.IsEmpty) {
                    if (op.Execute()) {
                        // create chained operation to remove cutout area from original geometry
                        var modifyOp = op.CreateChainedOperation();
                        var oDict = new Dictionary<string, object>();
                        oDict["SHAPE"] = GeometryEngine.Instance.Difference(oGeom, sketchGeom);
                        modifyOp.Modify(mapMember, oid, oDict);

                        if (!modifyOp.IsEmpty) {
                            var result = modifyOp.Execute();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    });
} else {
    MessageBox.Show("Please select 1 feature.");
}
return base.OnSketchCompleteAsync(sketchGeom);

}
Resulting operation:

